# JavaScript to hide and show form using select option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `formOne` and `formTwo` in select option. JavaScript code to hide the two form and if I select `formOne` to display `formOne`, if i select `formTwo` to display `formOne` and `formTwo`.

```js
function changeOptions(selectEl) {
  let selectedValue = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].value;
  let subForms = document.getElementsByClassName('OLevelResult')
  for (let i = 0; i < subForms.length; i += 1) {
    if (selectedValue === subForms[i].name) {
      subForms[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:block')
    } else {
      subForms[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:none')
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="changeOptions(this)">
  <option value="form_1">1</option>
  <option value="form_2">2</option>
</select>

<form class="OLevelResult" name="form_1" id="form_1" style="display:none">
  THIS IS FORM 1
  <!---- THIS IS FORM 1---->
</form>

<form class="OLevelResult" name="form_2" id="form_2" style="display:none">
  THIS IS FORM 2
  <!---- THIS IS FORM 2---->
</form>
```

Comment: I think your code is working fine. What issue you are facing?

Comment: it seems to work, only thing i recommend is adding and removing css classes instead of manipulating direct attributes

Comment: yes is working fine but i want to display form1 and form2 together if select 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function changeOptions(selectEl) {
  let subForms = document.getElementsByClassName('OLevelResult')
  for (let i = 0; i < subForms.length; i += 1) {
    if (selectEl === subForms[i].name) {
      for(let j=i; j>-1 ;j--) {
        subForms[j].classList.add("active");
      }
    } else {
      subForms[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.OLevelResult {
display: none;
}
.OLevelResult.active {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="changeOptions(this.value)">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="form_1">1</option>
  <option value="form_2">2</option>
  <option value="form_3">3</option>
  <option value="form_4">4</option>
</select>

<form class="OLevelResult" name="form_1" id="form_1">
  THIS IS FORM 1
  <!---- THIS IS FORM 1---->
</form>

<form class="OLevelResult" name="form_2" id="form_2">
  THIS IS FORM 2
  <!---- THIS IS FORM 2---->
</form>

<form class="OLevelResult" name="form_3" id="form_3">
  THIS IS FORM 3
  <!---- THIS IS FORM 1---->
</form>

<form class="OLevelResult" name="form_4" id="form_4">
  THIS IS FORM 4
  <!---- THIS IS FORM 2---->
</form>
```

Comment: yes is working fine but i want to display form1 and form 2 if select 2. thank you

Comment: Are you wanting javascript necessary? We can try this with jQuery